# Does Photos.app support a watch directory?

Tags: macos, photos.app

Is it possible for Photos to automatically include all files in a given directory as part of its Library? Picasa, for example, offers this.

I have a folder on my computer that is automatically synced to other devices via an online service (e.g. Dropbox, OneDrive, etc). Although I can manually import those files into Photos, that requires performing the import every time new files are added to that directory.

I have tried creating a new Photos library (holding down Option on launch) in the directory mentioned earlier to see if it might magically add all the files there, but that has no effect.

Comment: There is currently no watch directory functionality, which is what you are requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photos does not currently support a watch directory - meaning that all photos have to be imported manually (by dragging and dropping onto the Photos window or File > Import...) or via iCloud Photo Library or My Photo Stream.

Comment: Now, can we start a petition for this feature somewhere? Heh.